# How do i parse the current exactly letter/char only?

Tags: c#, winforms

The code:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Obtain the character index where the user clicks on the control.
    int positionToSearch = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    string word = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(positionToSearch);
    words.Add(word); // to get the specific word the mouse is on !
}
```

The problem is that each word in the List also contain the rest of the file content until the end.
I want to have letters/chars in List when mouse was over in the richTextBox 
when there is space /r/n and the rest of the content of the file each time im moving over a word.

This is an example of the words List content:

For example in index 0 i see:

```
Satellite Weather Europe, Weather Forecast, Rainfall, Clouds, Sun in Europe - Source: SAT24.com" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><meta
```

And its very long until the end of the file content.

In index 1 for example i see:

```
atellite Weather Europe, Weather Forecast, Rainfall, Clouds, Sun in Europe - Source: SAT24.com" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><meta
```

What i want to do is if there is a word: Satellite
And i move the mouse over the letter S of the Satellite then the first index in the List will be S 
Then if i moved to another word then the spoecific letter i moved over.
If it was the char '"' then index 67 will be "
If the char is ')' the nth index will contain the char )

And so on.

I want to add the List the current letter/char the mouse moved over not a word.
So the List in the end should look like for example:

index 0: "S"
index 1: ")"
index 2: "u"

Comment: What about `if (positionToSearch > -1) { string word = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(positionToSearch, 1); ... }`? You may find it's more useful to change the collection from strings to chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps,this only grabs the current character;

```
// Obtain the character index where the user clicks on the control.
int positionToSearch = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
char currentChar = richTextBox1.Text[positionToSearch];// Get the character the cursor is on.
words.Items.Add(currentChar); // Add the current character to our list.
```